# Rectangles in rectangles and $(b^2-a^2)^2\le (ax-by)^2+(bx-ay)^2$

Tags: mg.metric-geometry, polynomials

When does an $a\times b$ rectangle fit inside an $x\times y$ rectangle? I have an algebraic condition which I can diagram geometrically, and I'd like a good geometric argument.

Assume $0<a<b$, $0<x<y$. Then the one rectangle fits in the other iff $a\le x$ and either:
$$b\le y$$
or:
$$(b^2-a^2)^2 \le (ax-by)^2+(ay-bx)^2$$
which I found [algebraically](https://mathoverflow.net/a/365426/44143), with help from Mathematica. One possible diagram is

[image]

and then the last condition is equivalent to
$$
|\boldsymbol{\alpha \times \beta}|^2 \le
|\boldsymbol{\alpha \times \gamma}|^2 +
|\boldsymbol{\beta \times \gamma}|^2
$$
This can also be interpreted in terms of the lengths of these three vectors and the sines of the angles between them.

Is there a nice geometric argument from this diagram to fitting the one rectangle inside the other?

Comment: Could you specify the meaning of "fits"? By translation or by translation and rotation?

Comment: Yes, by translation and rotation.

Comment: Also posted to https://mathoverflow.net/questions/282158/how-to-check-if-a-box-fits-in-a-box/365426#365426

Comment: @GerryMyerson, I don’t think “also posted” is fair — they are related, but that was a partial answer to a request for an algorithm, and this is a question which explicitly links there and asks for a geometric explanation of that answer.

Comment: Sorry, Matt, I missed that you had linked this question to that one.

Answer (score 7):

The sense of this inequality is that it turns out into equality when one of rectangles is inscribed in another as on the picture. [image]

We get $ax-by=a(m+n)-b(p+q)=am-bp=a^2\cos \varphi-b^2\cos \varphi=(a^2-b^2)\cos \varphi$, analogously $ay-bx=a(p+q)-b(m+n)=aq-bn=(a^2-b^2)\sin \varphi$, and your relation $(a^2-b^2)^2=(ax-by)^2+(ay-bx)^2$ reads as $\cos^2\varphi+\sin^2 \varphi=1$.

Comment: Do you how to extend this reasoning to justify the inequality? The difference of the two sides is not obviously monotonic in any of the variables.

Comment: RHS is monotonic in $y$ when $y\geqslant x$ (take the derivative). Does not it help?

Comment: Now I see it, I got confused by the 2s and 4s.